NodeJS can't find module when running in Docker container
I am trying to dockerize a node.js application (called "Hub") on a docker for windows with Linux-based containers, but when building/running the container cannot access a dependency. The application is part of a microservice-architecture, where I have several local common-modules that are shared between the various services. The Hub-service does not use any volumes.
In this particular case, the affected service makes use of an authentication-module and a helper-module. The authentication-module includes the helper-module as well. This seems to be the issue.
The error I receive is:
hub-1  | Error: Cannot find module 'helper'
hub-1  | Require stack:
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Common/Authentication/index.js
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Hub/WS/eventhandler.js
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Hub/WS/initws.js
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Hub/index.js
hub-1  |   requireStack: [
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Common/Authentication/index.js',
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Hub/WS/eventhandler.js',
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Hub/WS/initws.js',
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Hub/index.js'
hub-1  |   ]
hub-1  | }

The folder structure is following the suggestion from: Setting up docker nodejs application with local npm dependencies
It looks like this:
Main Folder
|- <Dockerfiles for each service>-> "Dockerfile_Hub"
|- compose.yaml (Docker-compose)
|-apps
  |-Hub
  |- ...several other services
  |-Common
    |-Authentication
    |-Helper 
    |- ... several other common modules

In the dockerfile I copy ALL commonly used modules to the container and then run the npm install command. I have another service, where this works flawlessly, it seems to have something to do with file paths in interdepedencies between common-modules (Authentication-module has a dependency on the helper-module as well).
Package.json-files:
{
  "name": "hub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Hub Service",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "authentication": "file:../Common/Authentication",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "config": "file:../Common/Config",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.19.1",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "helper": "file:../Common/Helper",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "keycloak-connect": "^24.0.2",
    "logger": "file:../Common/Logger",
    "node-jose": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0"
  }
}


{
  "name": "authentication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "config": "file:../Config",
    "helper": "file:../Helper",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jswt": "^1.4.4",
    "logger": "file:../Logger"
  }
}


Docker files (as suggested in the mentioned article):

ARG NODE_VERSION=20.12.0

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p /src
COPY ./apps/Common /src/apps/Common
COPY ./apps/Hub /src/apps/Hub

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.npm to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mounts to package.json and package-lock.json to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/apps/Hub/package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=/apps/Hub/package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --omit=dev


RUN cd /src/apps/Hub && npm install

# Run the application as a non-root user.
USER node

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD node /src/apps/Hub/index.js


Docker-compose:
version: "3"

#Hub

services:
  hub:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Hub
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      APP_PATH: /src/apps/Hub
      PINO_LOG_LEVEL: debug
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

The build-process runs without any errors:
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:default
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:defaultr reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
[+] Building 3.2s (15/15) FINISHED                                                                                                                  
 => [hub internal] load build definition from Dockerfile_Hub                                                                                        
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.38kB                                                                                                              
 => [hub] resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                                    
 => CACHED [hub] docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:a57df69d0ea827fb7266491f2813635de6f17269be881f696fbfdf2d83dda33e               
 => [hub internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20.12.0-alpine                                                                          
 => [hub internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                               
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                     
 => [hub stage-0 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:20.12.0-alpine@sha256:ef3f47741e161900ddd07addcaca7e76534a9205e4cd73b2ed091ba339004a75            
 => [hub internal] load build context                                                                                                               
 => => transferring context: 478.86kB                                                                                                               
 => CACHED [hub stage-0 2/8] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                   
 => CACHED [hub stage-0 3/8] RUN mkdir -p /src                                                                                                      
 => CACHED [hub stage-0 4/8] COPY ./apps/Common /src/apps/Common                                                                                    
 => CACHED [hub stage-0 5/8] COPY ./apps/Hub /src/apps/Hub                                                                                          
 => CACHED [hub stage-0 6/8] RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/apps/Hub/package.json,target=package.json     --mount=type=bind,source=/apps/Hub/package-
 => CACHED [hub stage-0 7/8] RUN cd /src/apps/Hub && npm install                                                                                    
 => [hub stage-0 8/8] WORKDIR /src/apps/Hub                                                                                                         
 => [hub] exporting to image                                                                                                                        
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                             
 => => writing image sha256:4f2ce3b43d06485ec72da1c107df361e6b0a11d44785beea3baff85ff60170a3                                                        
 => => naming to docker.io/library/finslice-hub                                                                                                     
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container crazy_rosalind  Removed
 ✔ Container finslice-hub-1  Recreated
Attaching to hub-1
hub-1  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
hub-1  |   throw err;
hub-1  |   ^
hub-1  | 
hub-1  | Error: Cannot find module 'helper'
hub-1  | Require stack:
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Common/Authentication/index.js
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Hub/WS/eventhandler.js
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Hub/WS/initws.js
hub-1  | - /src/apps/Hub/index.js
hub-1  |   requireStack: [
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Common/Authentication/index.js',
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Hub/WS/eventhandler.js',
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Hub/WS/initws.js',
hub-1  |     '/src/apps/Hub/index.js'
hub-1  |   ]
hub-1  | }
hub-1  |
hub-1  | Node.js v20.12.0
hub-1 exited with code 1

If I access the containers file system I see that all files/folders are properly copied.
Container file system
It has probably something to do with the way I set the WORKDIR / CD-commands in the docker-file. I tried changing this to (last 2 lines of dockerfile):
WORKDIR /src/apps/Hub
CMD node index.js
with the same result.
Running the application just via node.js outside of docker works without any issues.

Why did you start your path from the root? Like /src/apps/Common. it  should be ./src/apps/Common. It can be seen throughout the docker file. It is much better to use COPY . . and ignore unwanted files using a .dockerignore file.

I have finally solved this.
After trying out Raeisi's tipp and moving to .dockerignore files instead of only selectively copying the files I took a closer look at the file system in a copy of the container.
What happens is: npm install for internal depedencies (i.e. npm install ../Common/Authentication etc.) only creates symlinks to the folder, but does not actually copies the module into the folder. Would probably work, if I worked on a Linux-machine, but on a windows-machine the symlinks refer to a windows-style directory (i.e. d:\myApp\myModule), which of course will not work in a linux based container.
What solved the issue is this article:
Install npm local module directory without symlinks?
simple solution: "use npm install --install-links ../module" instead of "npm install ../module". This will copy the entire source as if it was an external package.
